# Unknown entity exception when Entities are in multiple jars

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am getting this exception while running maven test.

> ERROR - Application could not be
>   deployed:  classpath.ear
>   org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException:
>   Creating application failed:
>   classpath.ear:
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
>   @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on
>   net.atos.wlp.cns.core.record.ClearingRecord.clearingBatch
>   references an unknown entity:
>   net.atos.wlp.cns.core.batch.ClearingBatch:
>   @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on
>   net.atos.wlp.cns.core.record.ClearingRecord.clearingBatch
>   references an unknown entity:
>   net.atos.wlp.cns.core.batch.ClearingBatch
>                   at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:658)

I tried with  &  option in persistence.xml file, still the error exists.

Please help me out if anyone face the similar issue.

Comment: Is that entity is accessible in program or shows any error in IDE.

Comment: I have the idea that you need a persistent unit per jar that contains entities, as the PU is configured in the META-INF folder of the jar.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem - by having my entities spread across multiple jar files. I also used maven...

at first I was able to get it to run by extracting the jar file into classes. In the end the solution was to specify the jar files of the dependency in the persitence.xml:

```
    ...
    <persistence-unit ...
    <provider>...</provider>
    <jar-file>WEB-INF/lib/my-jar-file-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar-file>
    <properties>
    ...
```

Comment: +1000.  Works, but what a horrible solution!  Hard to believe that Hibernate cant handle this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two classes, with the same name and same package in the same classloader, the result is a non-consistent behavior (in the sense that it may behave differently based on the combination of JVM/Application Server you choose). You may want to do some research on what would be the expected behavior for your JVM / Application Server, but the ideal solution is *not* to have the same class (in the same package) in two jars. If you *have* to do that, I'd say that you have an architecture problem that must be solved ;-)